# Add values to map using rapidjson

Tags: c++, json, stdmap, rapidjson

I get a raw json string

```
{"vehicle": {"brand": "zonda","color": "blue"},"username": {"brand": "doyota","color": "red"}}
```

from a get call i make.

I read that rapidjson is the best way to parse a json string in cpp.

So I tried doing something like this:

```
const char* json = data.c_str();
rapidjson::Document document;
if (document.Parse(json).HasParseError()) {

    cout << "has parse error" << endl;

    return 1;
}
else {
    assert(document.IsObject());
}
```

Here it says that the json has a parse error. Any idea why this could be?

Also once I am able to parse the values I want to add them as key value pairs to a standard map. Could anyone point me in the right direction to proceed with this?

Comment: RapidJSON allows you to check what the error is. Have you tried looking at the specific error code? The list is pretty extensive: http://rapidjson.org/md_doc_dom.html#ParseError

Comment: As far as the map is concerned, I've been working on something similar recently. The closest I found to a true JSON (and Python dictionary) is an `std::unordered_map` with a key type `std::string` and a value type of `std::variant<>`, where the variant could be int, float, string, vector, etc. `std::variant` requires C++17, though.

Comment: @ahota the error says "invalid values". Although i suspect this could be because I am converting a standard string to const char*? Also i am restricted to cpp 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gave me no error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "rapidjson/document.h"
#include "rapidjson/error/en.h"

using namespace rapidjson;

int main() {
    Document d;
    std::string json = R"raw({"vehicle": {"brand": "zonda","color": "blue"},"username": {"brand": "doyota","color": "red"}})raw";

    if (d.Parse(json.c_str()).HasParseError()) {
        std::cout << "has error\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "no error\n";
    }
}
```

Tried C++11 - C++20 and it all seems fine. My guess is that you've got some non UTF8 character in the data.

Comment: Oh nice this worked for me too. I there a significance to the R and the prefixed and suffixed raw here? Thing is, I get the json string from a get call.

{"vehicle": {"brand": "zonda","color": "blue"},"username": {"brand": "doyota","color": "red"}}

I don't actually have this in the code. can I append R or "raw" like we do in java? I am kinda cpp newbie so out of my depth here.

Comment: The `R"delimiter( raw_characters )delimiter"` only does you good with string literals so my guess is that you've got some non UTF8 character in the data but it's hard to say. But at least you know the parser is working. The string you get, can you save it in binary mode to a file and then perhaps validate it so that it is UTF8 encoded?

Comment: That was it! I was being rather stupid and returning VERBOSE and HEADER in libcurl get call. With just the JSON string in the body it works correctly!

Comment: Have you ever played around with pulling out the the json key value pairs? Trying to figure out a way to iterate them into a standard map.

Comment: Great! Sorry to say, I have very little experience with rapidjson. I settled with [JSON for Modern C++](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) eventually but I don't know how to do that there either. I've only been doing very basic stuff with it.